# Achieve synchronization in multi-threaded counter Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a program which I wrote to run multiple threads that increment counter. I am trying to use synchronization to avoid race conditions.

This is the code,
**Main method**

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Counter {

    public static void main(String... args) {


        System.out.println("Program started");

        AtomicInteger sum = new AtomicInteger(0);
        System.out.println("Initial Sum : " + sum.get());

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Thread workerThread = new WorkerThread(sum, i);
            workerThread.start();
        }

        System.out.println("Final Sum : " + sum.get());

    }
}
```

**WorkerThread**

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class WorkerThread extends Thread {

   private final AtomicInteger localSum;

    public WorkerThread(AtomicInteger sum, int i){
        localSum = sum;
        System.out.println(localSum.get());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (localSum) {
            localSum.incrementAndGet();
        }
    }
}
```

But apperently the synchronization does not work as expected (It does not prontout 100 at the end). Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Answers below both are correct, but they both save the important part for last. The important part is that your `main()` loop does not wait for the threads to finish. (I.e., it does not `join()` them.) The part about not needing `synchronized` is true, but that's only a performance issue. It does not affect the correctness of your program.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your program:

- You are using AtomicInteger, so you don't need to synchronize explicitly.
- You are not waiting for the threads to finish. The sum will reach 100 after all the threads run.

Put the threads you created in a list, and `join()` them before you print the result.

Answer (score 1):

Your `synchronized` is completely unnecessary. The `AtomicInteger` by itself is enough to make the code thread-safe. You would need a mutable non-atomic integer (which the standard JDK doesn't have) to actually see how `synchronized` works here, so this example isn't very good for that.

Your mistake is assuming that all the threads have finished running when the main thread calls `sum.get()`. You can make sure of that by having the main thread call `join()` on all the started threads for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    Thread workerThread = new WorkerThread(sum, i);
    workerThread.start();
    myThreads.add(workerThread);
}
for(Thread t : myThreads) {
    t.join();
}
```